# Office developer tools wont install VSTO not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-office

I'm trying to install the microsoft office developer tools. I downloaded them from this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/26/the-latest-of-microsoft-office-developer-tools-office-add-in-commands-and-sharepoint-2016-support/).

When trying to install I get this error message.
[image: Error message]

This is the about page from my Visual Studio Client.
[image: About VSTO]

What can I do to get the developer tools to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove old version studio and dependency with them and install visual studio community edition https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/